# Как получить дату в нужном формате одной командой? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как получить дату в формате YYYY/MM/DD HH:NN, я знаю есть команды для получения года, месяца и т.д. с которыми можно собрать строку, так как мне надо, но вот хотелось бы узнать, есть ли одна команда, дающая нужный результат?

Comment: в яваскрипте весьма бедный набор операций для работы с датами, в том числе и форматирование вывода дат.  _Как получить дату в нужном формате одной командой?_ - напиши функцию, и будешь получать одной командой: вызовом функции

Comment: @Grundy если не будет готовой, я так и сделаю

Comment: Нативной функции нет. Но есть куча библиотек, например momentjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я для себя сделал вот такой хелпер:

```js
Date.prototype.format = function(format = 'yyyy-mm-dd') {
    const replaces = {
        yyyy: this.getFullYear(),
        mm: ('0'+(this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        dd: ('0'+this.getDate()).slice(-2),
        hh: ('0'+this.getHours()).slice(-2),
        MM: ('0'+this.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        ss: ('0'+this.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
    };
    let result = format;
    for(const replace in replaces){
        result = result.replace(replace,replaces[replace]);
    }
    return result;
};
        
        
console.log((new Date()).format('yyyy/mm/dd hh:MM'))
```

Comment: Я не пойму, первое как мне присвоить это в  document.getElementById('elem').value = , второе где вызов первой функции? что бы она выполнилась

Comment: Данный метод возвращает обычную строку. Присваивайте так же, как вы обычно присваиваете строки.

Comment: Я правильно понял процесс, Date.prototype.format это вы создали новое свойство Дате?

Comment: Да, с помощью этого метода вы можете любой объект Date превратить в строку в нужном вам формате

Comment: Спасибо! Полностью подходит

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать след:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour12: true }));
```

Comment: не пойму как использовать, console.log сохраняет в date дату в нужном мне формате? как ее сохранить в: document.getElementById('elem').value =

Comment: @ArtGrek13,  _console.log_ - выводит строку в консоль.

Comment: уберите console.log, записывайте данные в переменную, например так `var myFormat = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour12: true })` и используйте эту переменную так где вам нужно