# Как получить дату в таком формате в javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Нужен такой формат даты. Есть ли нативные javascript функции чтобы получить текущую дату в таком формате?

```
2017-12-20T15:46:17+03:00
```

Comment: Тут есть все методы - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date, но как вам надо так и не нашёл, есть похожий toISOString, но это не то

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676806/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-javascript/676817#676817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, почти. Можно дальше форматировать строку если нужна точность до запятых в формате вывода. Что бы год показывало первым, нужно изменить 'ukl' на американский (кажется у них так принято). Немогу сейчас вспомнить их аббревиатуру:)
Вот тут можно почитать подробнее о атрибуте locales https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation

```js
var a = new Date();
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', timeZoneName: 'short' };
console.log(a.toLocaleDateString('ukl', options));
```