# Javascript сколько времени осталось до конца дня

Tags: javascript

нужен скрипт который будет выводить оставшееся время до конца дня в таком формате: часы;минуты;секунды

В интернете нахожу только старые примеры, которые у меня почему-то не работают!
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Во-первых, определитесь, что такое конец дня — по чьим часам, по какому часовому поясу? Во-вторых, примеры в интернете вполне работают (даже старые), это вы сами делаете что-то неправильно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить дату в нужном формате одной командой? JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676806/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант для московского времени. Если надо локальное время, то смотрите прошлый вариант в редактированых версиях поста или замените `moskow()` на `new Date()`.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  const t = endtime - moskow()
  let obj = {
    // days: t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) | 0
    hours: t / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24 | 0,
    minutes: t / 1000 / 60 % 60 | 0,
    seconds: t / 1000 % 60 | 0
  }

  for (let key in obj)
    obj[key] = ('0' + obj[key]).slice(-2)
  
  return obj
}
const dayEnd = moskow()
dayEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)

setInterval(() => {
  const result = getTimeRemaining(dayEnd)
  const formated = Object.values(result).join(':')

  display.innerHTML = formated
}, 500)

// get moskow date
function moskow () {
    const offset = 3 // moskow offset
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime((new Date().getTime()) + 
              (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000) + // local offset
              (1000 * 60 * 60 * offset)); // target offset
    return d
}
```

```html
<span id="display"></span>
```

Comment: А можно привязать этот счетчик к Московскому времени?

Comment: Сделал для москвы